# Strange behaviour when updated to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

[image]

The above contents are placed in a scrollview but the output in the app is as below [image]

If i place these contents outside the scrollview it is working fine, it was working fine before update to xcode 8

Comment: It's just a guess, but does this still happen if you set the contentMode of the affected views to Redraw?

Comment: can you show ur view Hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these constraints for UIScrollView [image]

Comment: I am not using constraint in this project :(

Comment: did you used autolayout?

Comment: then you can set the above constraints to your UIScrollView

Comment: sorry i am not using autolayout

Comment: Then you can use Autoresizing

Answer (score 0):

Don't change anything layout **(Autoresizing/Autolayout)**. I think the issue is scrollview content size. So, you update the view frame in `viewDidLoad` method. And after then update scrollview content size.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    //set view frame
    self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
}
```